# Get plugin versions in xml/json format

Tags: plugins

We have quite a few wordpress sites running and it would be nice to have the wordpress version and all of the plugins + version used in one seperate place.

We have our own dashboard with information about each site already (uptime/loadings times etcetc) it would be nice to add installed plugins there.

Is there a way to get all the installed plugins + their version in some format other than scaping the html?

Comment: What are you using for your "dashboard" system? Bespoke or public?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic just some custom php scripts with cronjobs to gather the information, nothing special and we can add whatever we want. I'm just not sure how to gather the plugin information via get requests

Comment: The active plugins are stored in serialized array in the wp_options table with the option_name of active_plugins.  You can get what all plugins are present by reading the plugin directory programmatically.

Comment: @Xeli Have you thought about using a readily-available system like [WP Remote](https://wpremote.com) (hosted) or [InfiniteWP](https://infinitewp.com/) (self-hosted)? That would do everything you're after, and more!